# Massive difference for dxgkrnl.sys in poolmon, large paged-pool

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

Here's a list of my systems components if that will help. I have an [IMGur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDjfS.jpg) highlighting a good bit of my problem currently.

`Dxgkrnl.sys` is constantly causing a massive leak into my paged pool (It can get over 6GB or more) and severely slows down my computer. The problem starts occurring mostly when I'm streaming sports events, or Netflix.

These are my current hardware system specs:

- Motherboard: GIGABYTE Z170XP-SLI
- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700k
- Memory:

  - 2x 8 GB PC4-24000 DDR4-SDRAM G Skill F4-3000C15-8GVKB Memory
  - 1x 4 GB PC4-24000 DDR4-SDRAM G Skill F4-3000C15-4GRBB Memory
- GPU: MSI R9 390 Gaming (MS-V308)
- HD (Boot): Samsung SSD850 EVO 250GB HD (Storage): WDC WD10EZEX-00BN5A0 1000GB
- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home (x64)

Any help is incredibly appreciated and I can run any software scans and post results if asked for, if it will help you in figuring out my situation.

Comment: Update your graphics card drivers. What browser are you using to stream video? Check TaskManager and see what your GPU usage is while streaming video. If it's idle, you need to enable hardware acceleration in your browser.

Comment: I use Chrome to stream the video, my GPU usage can make it all the way up to like 60-70% for sometimes a single stream which doesn't seem right to me. I will check on hardware acceleration. I will also make sure that I'm not missing a update on my graphics card drivers.